# How to insert content in text box when drop down menu item is changed in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the following code i wish to insert a value corresponding to the drop down menu `Invoiceno` in the text box `TotalAmount`. Also i wish to enable a text box `ChequeNumber` if the value of drop down menu `PaymentMode` is cheque. 
But the values appear in the text box only after i press the submit button. What am i doing wrong?

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

  namespace OrderManagementSystem
  {
  public partial class MakePayment : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    Dictionary<int, int> InvoiceAmount = new Dictionary<int, int>();



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChequeNumber.Enabled = false;

    }

    protected void InvoiceNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InvoiceAmount.Add(1111, 100000);
        InvoiceAmount.Add(2222, 200000);
        InvoiceAmount.Add(3333, 300000);
        InvoiceAmount.Add(4444, 400000);


        int InvoiceValue = Convert.ToInt32(InvoiceNo.SelectedValue);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in InvoiceAmount)
        {
            if (InvoiceValue == item.Key)
            {
                TotalAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(item.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void PaymentMode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PaymentMode.SelectedValue == "Cheque")
        {

            ChequeNumber.Enabled = true;

            if (ChequeNumber.Text=="")
            {

            }
        }

    }

    protected void TotalAmount_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add AutoPostBack="true" on your DropDowlList declaration. This will make the page post to the server when the value is changed. You may consider adding UpdatePanel to make the postback via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

1>  add AutoPostBack="true" on DropDownList in your .aspx page.

2> the second problem lies in your page load function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{    
     ChequeNumber.Enabled = false;  
}
```

the textbox ChequeNumber is disabled every time when the page is loaded.
To resolve this issue you need to keep the state of `ChequeNumber` in `ViewState["xyz"]`